# Angular 9 Plugin Architecture

Tags: angular9

I have currently written an Angular 9 application, this consists of components and services.

**The goal**

I have in mind is to be able to override the existing html templates and/or the entire component using a plugin architecture.

I have been following the code located on GitHub here: https://github.com/apoprotsky/angular-plugin-architecture

**The Problem**

I am not able to use/import my services that deal with authentication, fetching data or dealing with forms etc.

**Things I've Tried**

- Just importing it - doesn't work
- Attempted to move all the relevant services to a separate module and load this into both the core app and the plugin, this works for the core app, but does not work for the plugin (it can't find it) - doesn't work

So, the question is, is what I'm trying to do at all possible - if so, what are the best methods for doing so, i feel like the github repo noted above is almost what I'm needing to achieve, but as stated, importing services etc do not work.